# Важно ли использование --no-ff при слиянии веток?

Tags: git, git-merge

При слиянии веток в git можно указать флаг `--no-ff`, который отключит fast-forward. Какие есть +/- `--no-ff` кроме возможности увидеть красивый график наследования веток? Где вы используете `--no-ff`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`--no-ff` удобен для реверта. Если много людей делают код и много коммитят в свои ветки (а в случае гита - это абсолютно нормально), то с включенным fast-forward история превратится в нечитаемое мессиво. И если потом нужно будет какой-то объем работ откатить, то это может быть сложно. Да, я знаю о том, что коммиты можно перегруппировать перед мерджем. Но некоторых нужно ещё научить этому.

В одном с моих проектов этот флаг установлен глобально по желанию менеджмента.